# OCamlbuild not resolving subdirectory dependency

Tags: ocaml, ocamlbuild

I have an OCaml project and I'm running into a weird issue.

The directory structure looks like this:

```
./tests
    test.ml
    templatetest.ml
./src
    template.ml
    ...
    andsoforth.ml
```

I am building it like this:

```
ocamlbuild -Is src,tests tests/test.native
```

**Key point being, tests/test.ml depends on tests/templatetest.ml.**

When I build it, I get:

```
+ /usr/local/bin/ocamlc.opt -c -I tests -I src -o tests/test.cmo tests/test.ml
File "tests/test.ml", line 1, characters 0-17:
Error: Unbound module TemplateTest
Command exited with code 2.
Compilation unsuccessful after building 2 targets (0 cached) in 00:00:00.
```

I tried adding a _tags file in the top directory containing:

```
<src> or <tests>: include
```

That still produced the same error. (I believe ocamlbuild tests/test.native with the _tags file is the exact same thing as the previous build line I used.)

I also created an empty _tags file in both ./tests and ./src, but that didn't change anything either.

Any suggestions? If you need, the entire source is [here](https://github.com/eatonphil/owebl/tree/templates). Just run `make test`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It a funny issue: not `TemplateTest` but `Templatetest`. For the former name, you module file should be named `templateTest.ml`